# Blackberry Access to Powered Down Exchange

Tags: exchange, blackberry

I work with a company (it's more of a charity really) who have a single Exchange Server, with a few Blackberry users, who download emails via POP3 or IMAP.

They are in a developing country and so every night they turn off the Exchange server to save power. However, they now want the Blackberry users to be able to get mail at night. They have a Linux server (a rented VPS), so they are considering having the mail delivered here and then pulling this mail via a POP connector into Exchange. Therefore at night, the BES users (who will now be pulling their POP email from the Linux server) can still get their mail.

Can anyone think of a better solution to this problem that I may have missed? Unfortunately there is no convincing the company to leave the machine on overnight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eww... ick. Sorry to hear that you have to deal with that kind of hard-headedness...

Have they considered just going to hosted Exchange, rather than making a mess like this? Not having a powered-on Exchange Server computer on their site *at all* might make them happier and would certainly be less messy.h

Comment: Yeah, it's one of the things I'm going to suggest but i'm dubious they will stump up the cash to go for it, worth a go though.